# Check if the given relations are transitive and if not, add new pairs to make it transitive

Tags: c++, iterator, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to check if the given relations are transitive and if not, add new pairs of relations to make it transitive. Example input:

```
aa ab ad be
```

Function should make this:
`aa ab ad be ae` because in order to be transitive, if `ab` and `bc` exists, `ac` must exist too. But I get a segmentation fault whatever I try.

I'm new to C++ programming and trying to learn about iterators. Here is my function:

```
vector<string> isTransitive(vector<string> relations){
    bool flag;
    for(auto it=relations.begin();it != relations.end(); ++it){ 
        for(auto it2=relations.begin();it2 != relations.end(); ++it2){
            if((*it)[1] == (*it2)[0] && (*it)[0] != (*it)[1] && (*it2)[0]!=(*it2)[1]){ //if there exists ab and bc
                string newRelation;  //if there is a (a,b) (b,c) holds (a,c)
                newRelation.push_back((*it)[0]);
                newRelation.push_back((*it2)[1]);
                flag=false;
                for(auto it3=relations.begin();it3 != relations.end(); ++it3){
                    if(*it3==newRelation){
                        flag=true;
                        it3=relations.end(); //break the loop
                        it2=relations.end(); //break the loop
                    }
                }
                if(flag==false){
                    relations.push_back(newRelation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return relations;
}
```

`if(*it3==newRelation)` when this statement is `true`, I get the segfault.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you might miss new relations from your added new relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop is equivalent to a while loop (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)):

```
{

    init_statement
    while ( condition ) {

        statement
        iteration_expression ;

    } 

}
```

With this two lines:

```
it3=relations.end(); //break the loop
it2=relations.end(); //break the loop
```

You are not breaking the loop, but you cause undefined behavior. Both iterators will be incremented first, then the loop condition is checked. At that point `it3` is no longer `relations.end()`. It is more or less like this:

```
{
    auto it = relations.begin();
    while (it != relations.end()) {
        it = relations.end();
        ++it;
    }
}
```

The condition will never be `true` and you run beyond the end of `relations`.

To break out of loops use `break`. To break out of nested loops, you can put them in a function and use `return`.